# How do I replace the cartridge lever in my Moen bathroom faucet?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, cartridge

I'm trying to replace the cartridges on this Moen faucet.

I removed the cap and the screw but the lever just won't come off.  I tried pulling it off on every different angle. It appears the lever is a separate unit from the round base.

Is there any way to remove them?

This is the same issue for both levers. [This is a video](https://youtube.com/shorts/jwuJfTFp-Fw?feature=share) (YouTube) that shows what I'm talking about.

Comment: This is the video link to the problem.   https://youtube.com/shorts/jwuJfTFp-Fw?feature=share

Comment: use a screw driver insert in the slot and lift it up

Comment: Insert it in which slot?  Thank you

Comment: not a slot, it is a gap when you push the handle to the side

Comment: Are you referring to the gap between the lever and the round base?  Insert flat head screw in between?

Comment: It's more useful to include all links in the question itself (you can [edit] it), as comments get missed and sometimes deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove the lever by inserting a slotted screwdriver between the lever and the round base and twisting the screwdriver a little. Work your way round the lever doing the same thing. The lever should break free. Then lift or twist the round base to remove it and you'll see the nut you need to remove to remove the valve stem.

Comment: I will give it a try.  Thank you!

Comment: @James if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that the appropriate way to say "thanks" is to click the up vote button next to _every_ answer that was helpful to you, then to click the check mark next to the answer that helped you the _most_.